# How to get a facebook page's picture in this 168 pixels squared format?

Tags: facebook

It should not be simply the  full page  picture  redimensioned, but this cutted  one that facebook shows on the pages. for example https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/c21.21.259.259/s160x160/197503_163174873737023_6138040_n.jpg

if you compare to the original page  picture,

https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/197503_163174873737023_6138040_n.jpg

you see its different. I need to know where is this 168x168 stored in the   graph object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the page name or page id, you can make a request to `picture` endpoint and specify the type parameter.

For example, here is a request for the cocacola picture:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocalcola/picture?type=large
```